# Prisma 4.11 crash server if using await or .then over 6 request simultaneous

Tags: linux, next.js, prisma

My NextJs project is using Prisma 4.11 to connect to the database (PostgreSQL). When the server is Windows, I can generate a load of more than one hundred simultaneous requests without errors. When I put it to run on Linux, it doesn't go beyond six requests and the server stops, many times without showing any errors.

This error appears sometimes:
malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected.

I found that by removing the "await" and ".then" I can perform the same payload as in windows. The selects don't have a problem, I'm having a problem with create, update, delete.
I've tried running in dev or start mode.
On Vercel's servers it runs normally.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are probably running into this issue: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/18510